# Time Zone Conversions in Multiple Cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was working on this spreedsheet for my company and we need to get this document out to different people around the world. I want to reach out and see if there is way to do something like that. I've been scouring google and cannot locate what I need to solve this issue.

Example. Type in PDT in one cell and converts UTC, EET in separate cells.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Very rarely do people just simply write code for you. We'd like to see you put some effort into your code and display it in the question. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to see how.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to call [`Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format). The `timeZone` argument can be PDT, UTC, EET, etc.